# Non-social Provider with Django

Tags: python, django, authentication, oauth

Is there a 3rd party package to handle authentication for Django via OAuth? I've looked into OAuth Toolkit but it only seems to be a provider that provision tokens. I'm looking for something that can consume an existing provider much like All Auth does with Google, Facebook, etc. The problem is that I want to integrate with a private provider, not a popular social provider as mentioned above. Is there any package that could do this or do I have to write the OAuth flow entirely by myself?

Comment: Given it implements OAuth, I don't see the problem?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Given what? My company has an OAuth provider that I would like to use. I'm looking for a package that does the heavy lifting so I don't have to construct the authorization endpoint, code exchange, JWT parsing, user management myself.

Comment: Not entirely, but you should at least write some code as it's a private provider. Did you take a look at `https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core` (there's a django app based on this core) ? See "backends" section, it could be as easy as writing a custom backend for your organization. I thinks it's a good fit for your use case.

Comment: @gmarco Not really sure how to implement a backend but I'm sure I could figure it out if I saw some boilerplate. Kinda a shame django-oauth-toolkit doesn't have a client app, only a provider app.

Comment: Take a look in https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/tree/master/social_core/backends. There are plenty of backends  (Amazon, bitbucket, github, etc) u can take as example. Don't forget to upvote if I helped you :).